# How to stop one column from being sortable while Using JQuery UI sortable function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a table in my JSP page which starts like this

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight" id="tab_logic"></table>
```

I am adding rows to the table in this manner through an AJAX Call

```html
function loadData(data){
    var htm = "<tr><th style='width: 20%'>Index Order</th><th style='width: 20%'>Category Name</th><th style='width: 20%'>Category Key</th><th style='width: 20%'>Category Id</th></tr>";
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        htm += "<tr><td>" + data[i].indexOrder + "</td><td>" + data[i].name + "</td><td>" + data[i].catKey + "</td><td>" + data[i].id + "</td></tr>";           
    }
    $("#tab_logic").html(htm);
}
```

Now to make the table sortable I am using the jQuery UI plugin and using these lines

```html
$("#tab_logic").sortable({
    items: "tr:not(th)",
    helper: "clone",
    update: function() {
        // alert("success");
    }
}).disableSelection();

$("#submit").click(function(){
    process();
});
```

Now I want to all the other columns except the first one to be Sortable. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the jQuery data table to populate the data which provides rich set of functions.

We can configure the sorting columns and their respective sorting direction at the instantiate time of the dataTable. Check and see whether it can be used in your context

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Comment: @Tharasan Yeah it could be .But i have already made most of the project and it would be a lot of trouble changing the whole this again . So if you can help fix problem in the orignal table it would be great

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`items`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items) option to specify which items should be sortable.

Something like

```
items: 'tbody tr:not(:first-child)`
```

or if you can add a class like `enabled` to sortable rows, simply

```
items: 'tr.enabled'`
```